# How to access object property in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arraylist

I have following code to store object Inj in a arraylist $Inj_collection.

```
        function Inj($i) {
            this.$NameLink = _link("LV:" + $i + ":Name");
            this.$SeverityLink = _link("LV:" + $i + ":Severity");
            this.$DescriptionLink = _link("LV:" + $i + ":Description");
        }

        var $Inj_collection = [];
        var $line_number = 0;
        while (_exists(_link("LV:" + $line_number + ":Name"))) {
            var $temp = new Inj($line_number);
            $Inj_collection.push($temp);
            $line_number++;
        }

        var $inj_1=$Inj_collection[1].$NameLink; // can't get value of $NameLink.
```

However I can't use above way to access the property in object Inj. The $Inj_collection[1] only is recognized as general object, but not an Inj object.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `$Inj_collection` remains empty. Did you intend `this.$InjuryIncidents` instead?

Comment: Either you are missing some code in your sample or your implementation is wrong. Where is this.$InjuryIncidents coming from?

Comment: Updated the code. The $temp is added into $Inj_collection in original code. This is my copy error. I modified the code to make it simpler to put here:)

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the sample code provided and my assumption of your desired output, you could do the following.

In your sample code, you haven't added anything in the `$Inj_collection`. You have added the $temp in `this.$InjuryIncidents`.

```
        var $Inj_collection = [];
        var $line_number = 0;
        while (_exists(_link("LV:" + $line_number + ":Name"))) {
            var $temp = new Inj($line_number);
            $Inj_collection.push($temp);
            $line_number++;
        }
        var $inj_1=$Inj_collection[1].$NameLink;
```

Link to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: This won't work as I mentioned above: $Inj_collection[1] only is recognized as general object, but not an Inj object.

Comment: are you using some sort of framework? is it possible to create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Unless there is something else in your code, the above code should work. I have added a jsfiddle link in the answer.

Comment: Also make sure that _exists(_link("LV:" + $line_number + ":Name")) line of code is actually working and your while loop is actually working. May be your code is not even going through the loop and noting is added in the collection